# How do I make nginx proxy some urls on a domain to one location and the rest to somewhere else

Tags: nginx

I want `mydomain.com/`, `mydomain.com/a`, `mydomain.com/b` and `mydomain.com/c` to be proxied to `127.0.0.1:8001/site/*` and *everything else* on `mydomain.com` to `127.0.0.1:8002`.

These URLS are all on exactly the same domain, no subdomains involved. **I do not want to use a subdomain and it is not an option here.** The URLs are all on the same domain.

The first case also involves a rewrite to send things to a sub-folder. So:

```
http://mydomain.com/ -> http://127.0.0.1:8001/site/
http://mydomain.com/a -> http://127.0.0.1:8001/site/a
http://mydomain.com/b -> http://127.0.0.1:8001/site/b
http://mydomain.com/c -> http://127.0.0.1:8001/site/c
```

The second case is a "wildcard", so anything that's not going to 127.0.0.1:8001/site/* should go to 127.0.0.1:8002. So:

```
http://mydomain.com/monkey -> http://127.0.0.1:8002/monkey
http://mydomain.com/banana -> http://127.0.0.1:8002/banana
http://mydomain.com/x -> http://127.0.0.1:8002/x
```

So in pseudocode:

```
if domain is 'mysite.com'
  if path in ['/', '/a', '/b', '/c']
    proxy to 127.0.0.1:8001 + '/site' + path
  else
    proxy to 127.0.0.1:8002 + path
```

Everything I have tried so far has caused nginx to fall through and do one location's rewrites and pick up the last location's proxy_pass URL.

aside: Clearly the difficulty in figuring out how to do something this trivial proves why proper if/else support would *not* be evil ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to "rewrite" and "proxy_pass" directive in nginx manual and this can be solved easily:

```
location ~* "^/$|^/(a|b|c).*?$" {
    rewrite "^/(.*)$" /site/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    ......; // to add any commands you need
    break;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    ......; // to add any commands you need
    break;
}
```

Because no rewrite directive wrote in server block, Nginx start to match url in location phase. If is is caught by one location (here using the 1st one as example), then enter into rewrite loop. "break" in the end of rewrite means jump out the rewrite loop. Then start dealing with other directives in this location ,here proxy_pass will be dealt with.

General process in this case would be:

```
location match --> rewrite loop --> proxy_pass
      |                |
      | -----<---------|
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but the proxy_pass in the location / {} "catchall" always gets picked up along with the first location's rewrite. It is as if it doesn't work with break;

Comment: I just tried that again and now it works. I was initially testing by proxying to the same server which must have been what caused it to go weird. It was using everything like the rewrite rules from the first location, but just the proxy_pass line from the second. Sorry about that.